# How to find sum of singular values of a matrix using openCv

Tags: c++, opencv, svd

I am working on a problem which needs to calculate the nuclear norm pf a matrix which is sum of the singular values of the matrix. I have the input matrix as M and its number of Rows as mRows and number of Columns as mCols. What is wrong with the following code segment?

```
float neuclearNorm(float**M, int mRows, int mCols) {
    A = cv::Mat(mRows, mCols, CV_32FC1, &M);
    float count = 0;
    cv::SVD::compute(A, w, u, vt, CV::SVD::MODIFY_A, CV::SVD::NO_UV);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(w) / sizeof(w[0]); i++) {
        count += w[i];
    }
    return count;

}


int main(){
     int Rows=5,Cols=5;
     float ** Matrix=new float*[Rows];
     for(int i=0;i<Rows;i++){
          Matrix[i]=new float[Cols];
          for(int j=0;j<Cols;j++)
                cin>>Matrix[i][j];
          }
     cout<<"Neuclear norm"<<neuclearNorm(Matrix,Rows,Cols);
     return 0;
    };
```

Comment: What makes you say this code is wrong? What input do you give to it, what output to you get, and what output do you expect?

Comment: My input is a matrix M with floating point numbers and dimensions mRows and mCols. And I want to find the sum of all the singular values of the matrix M.

Comment: What I meant is that if you give more details, you are more likely to get an answer. Right now, you seem to expect that someone will create a project with your code, find some input and the expected output, and start debugging your code. If you actually give details (better, some executable code), then it's easier for people to help you. For instance, does SVD::compute give you the correct matrix, or not?

Comment: `sizeof(w) ` does most likely not do what you expect, depending on what `w` is.

Comment: w is a cv::Mat, you can use cv::sum to do the sum -> `double count = cv::sum(w)[0];` sizeof(w) will give the size of a cv::Mat which is kind of a header like struct